# Handle onclick event from custom d3 visualization on react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am trying to handle a clickevent from my d3 vis by transmitting data from vis.js to the referring React Component using Callbacks as described in
https://towardsdatascience.com/passing-data-between-react-components-parent-children-siblings-a64f89e24ecf

While trying to 'npm run build' the project the following error occurs:

```
src\charts\MyChart\vis.js
  Line 136:35:  'sendData' is not defined  no-undef
```

How can i call sendData() defined in index.js

Thank you all in advance!

**index.js**

The index.js in which i render am drawing my d3 chart

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import draw from './vis';

export default class MyChart extends Component {

    sendData = (d) => {
         console.log("hello world");
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    }

    componentDidUpdate(preProps) {
    draw(this.props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='vis-mychart ' sendData={this.sendData.bind(this)} ></div>
        )
    }

}
```

**vis.js**

where i want to send the data from

```
const draw = (props) => {
...

.on("click", function(d) {sendData(d)})
...
}
export default draw;
```

Comment: While it does not appear to be causing your error, if you are using d3v6 the function passed to `selection.on()` now must be of the form `function(event,d)` instead of `function(d)` - this may cause you issues after you address this error.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am using v4, so this should be fine :)